# Сложное предложение или простое?

Tags: пунктуация

Меня интересует: нужна ли запятая вот тут: "Каждая из них - произведение искусства(,) и ни одна не повторяется" (речь о мраморных скамьях в парке). Никак не могу сообразить, сложное это произведение или простое, соответственно, нужна запятая перед И или нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом предложении две грамматические основы, поэтому запятая нужна